# Repository does not have release file error for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04

I understand that 'repository does not have a release file' is a common error for old unsupported releases. But I get this error in a supported version.I tried changing 'in.archive...' to 'old-releases...' in /etc/apt/sources.list. But I still get the error. Below is my output.

```
    sambeet@Polya:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                       
Ign:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                 
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release                                     
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 10.10.78.62 3128]
Err:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release                                          
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 10.10.78.62 3128]
Ign:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                         
Ign:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                               
Err:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 10.10.78.62 3128]
Err:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 10.10.78.62 3128]
Err:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 10.10.78.62 3128]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
sambeet@Polya:~$
```

As you can see I changed one website to "http://old-releases.." but even that is showing no release file error. Can someone please suggest some work around? Here is my release info.

```
sambeet@Polya:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: No, for my case, it was different,please go through my answer below. It had something to do with the proxy in my workplace.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It was that apt does not use system proxy, I had to make a proxy.conf file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf where I added the proxy by following this [page](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-apt-for-ubuntu-18-04/). But the error message needed to be more particular. I would also like to know if there's any way I can make apt use the system wide proxy. By the way there are three places in which you should specify proxy in ubuntu 20.04...

1. In /etc/environment for curl to work
2. In /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf (Create the file if it not there) for apt to work
3. In /var/snap/cannonical-livepatch/config for livepatch to work

Comment: I won't expect `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal` to work, at least till 2025. Focal Fossa is still supported.